# Undesired PDF format from particular R Markdown YAML configuration

Tags: r, yaml, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

In R Studio, my R Markdown document begins like this:

````
---
title: 'ST 412: Homework 3'
author: "Camden White"
documentclass: amsart
geometry: margin=1in
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## 1. Read Data Set and Define Variables

```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
```
````

When I do not include `documentclass: amsart`, everything works fine, but when I do include it, the `library` section is placed *before* the `## 1. Read Data Set and Define Variables` header.

When there is text between the two components, the order is the same order in the code, but without it, the `library` section comes first. This does not happen with the default `article` document class, and I do not know why this occurs. How can I use the `amsart` document class and fix this ordering issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that a subsection in amsart is basically what a paragraph is in normal classes: an unnumbered bold piece of text without an new paragraph after it. The text will just continue in the same line. As the grey box with the source code spans a whole line, it can't be placed there and shows up above. You can reproduce this with normal article class like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{1. Read Data Set and Define}
\begin{framed}
test
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

You can avoid the problem by making sure the source code isn't the first text in the subsection, e.g. by adding something invisible:

````
---
title: 'ST 412: Homework 3'
author: "Camden White"
documentclass: amsart
geometry: margin=1in
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## 1. Read Data Set and Define Variables

\mbox{}
```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
```
````

[image]